# Eclipse Indigo marketplace

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-marketplace

I have installed Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 11.10, and the marketplace is not showing up under "Help" so I have added http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ to the software repositorys in "Install new software". When I try to update Eclipse with "Help" -> "Check for updates" it shows a few things that should update, but I cannot install the updates because this error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.1.r371_v20110810-0800-7z8gFcoFMLfTabvKsR5Qm9rBGEBK (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.1.r371_v20110810-0800-7z8gFcoFMLfTabvKsR5Qm9rBGEBK)
Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160331466 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160331466)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
  org.eclipse.rcp_root 3.7.0.dist-9gBsFnkFlfr2B21319
  org.eclipse.rcp_root 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9DB5FmNFnFLSFCtLxnRfMqt15A4A
  org.eclipse.rcp_root 3.7.0.v20110216-9DB5Fm1FpBGy_AaVz-mFamgY
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160331466 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160331466)
  To: org.eclipse.rcp_root [3.7.0.dist-9gBsFnkFlfr2B21319]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.1.r371_v20110810-0800-7z8gFcoFMLfTabvKsR5Qm9rBGEBK (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.1.r371_v20110810-0800-7z8gFcoFMLfTabvKsR5Qm9rBGEBK)
  To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.1
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9gF7UHOxFtniV7mI3T556iZN9AU8bEZ1lHMcVK)
  To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9DB5FmNFnFLSFCtLxnRfMqt15A4A]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: Eclipse RCP 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9DB5FmNFnFLSFCtLxnRfMqt15A4A (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9DB5FmNFnFLSFCtLxnRfMqt15A4A)
  To: org.eclipse.rcp_root [3.7.1.r37x_v20110729-9DB5FmNFnFLSFCtLxnRfMqt15A4A]
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if I had exact same error message or not. However, I was able to resolve similar issue by opening eclipse from root.

Environment:
Eclipse 3.7.0,
Ubuntu 11.10

Caution: I JUST DID THIS. LOOKS LIKE WORKING FINE. HOWEVER, PLEASE LET ME KNOW IF I MESSED IT UP ANYTHING.

1. Start terminal using (ctrl + alt + t)
2. `$sudo eclipse`
3. in eclipse go to "help->install new software"
4. click on "available software sites". That will open "preferences" window.
5. check if you have repositories mentioned below enabled. If not, then add them.

   `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo`
     `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7`
6. Now go back to eclipse main window and select "help->check for updates"
7. first update eclipse platform. That will update IDE from 3.7.0 to 3.7.1
8. update all other things.

Comment: The Android development tools is messed up. When I reïnstall it also doesn't work.

Comment: My android development worked. However, there are other issues related to new updates or installations. I have to log in as root every time I want to use it. That is not good. I am going to re install everything.

Comment: http://varunsaini06.blogspot.com/2012/01/install-eclipse-371-on-ubuntu-1110.html   This worked for me. From last 3 days I am using. So far no issues.

Comment: Permanent solution is to manually download eclipse, unzip it in home folder and run it from there.